# find match in child elements / trumbowyg

Tags: javascript, jquery, trumbowyg

I have a form and i must check element in textarea/ div with trumbowyg.

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val.match(/{event_title}/g)) {
    $("p.eventTagTitle").addClass("true");
  } else {
    $("p.eventTagTitle").removeClass("true");
  }
  if (val.match(/{event_form}/g)) {
    $("p.eventTagForm").addClass("true");
  } else {
    $("p.eventTagForm").removeClass("true");
  }
  if (val.match(/{event_author}/g)) {
    $("p.eventTagAuthor").addClass("true");
  } else {
    $("p.eventTagAuthor").removeClass("true");
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/f1m33312/3](http://jsfiddle.net/f1m33312/3)

but

in trumbowyg not works

[jsfiddle.net/f1m33312/4](http://%20%09%20jsfiddle.net/f1m33312/4)

similar solution in trumbowyg not work when add text to div

Comment: true, thanks Anonymous ;-)

Comment: because events happen  in the editor elements not the textarea. Examine the live html it produces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trumbowyg editor have special event: `tbwchange` (from http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html).

You should just replace one line

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
```

to

```
$("#test").on('tbwchange', function() {
```

Done on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f1m33312/6/

Comment: PS: Pozdrawiam :)

Comment: i również Cię Pozdrawiam ;-)